# Android notification from device 1 to 2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, notifications

I am developing an app for android using eclipse, what i'm basically trying to do is:

> send an notification form my device(1) to another device(2).

I am using user log in with is already configured with a database.

When I press down on user(when i press down on a button that sends the notification).

I want device 1 to send an notification that shows on device 2.

Both devices are logged in with different users, but I can't make the notification part to work.

**edit**: when I push the button the notification displays on device 1, but iI want it to display on device 2...

This is the code of receiving a notification:

```
public void NmRecv(String username, String message) 
{               

    FriendInfo friend = FriendController.getFriendInfo(username);
    MessageInfo msg = MessageController.checkMessage(username);
    if ( msg != null)
    {           
        Intent i = new Intent(TAKE_MESSAGE);
        i.putExtra(MessageInfo.USERID, msg.userid);         
        i.putExtra(MessageInfo.MESSAGETEXT, msg.messagetext);           
        sendBroadcast(i);
        String activeFriend = FriendController.getActiveFriend();
        if (activeFriend == null || activeFriend.equals(username) == false) 
        {
            localstoragehandler.insert(username,this.getUsername(), message.toString());
            showNotification(username, message);
        }


    }   

}
```

any ideas?

Comment: I think systems of socket.o will help you doing your needs.

Comment: http://fr.slideshare.net/sergialmar/building-realtime-applications-with-android-and-websockets

Comment: use web service on Google app Engine and Do need full work to send Push Notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can achieve that using [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html).**

**Also check this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html).**

You'll have to register the Android devices' keys in order to be able to send notifications.

In other words. You need to store the devices' keys in the Database when they log in.

And then when device1 wants to send a notification to device 2 you do that using GCM and the device 2 key that's stored in the database.

Here's an example of the code I'm using server side to send a message using GCM:

```
Sender sender = new Sender (SENDER_API_CODE);

Message message = new Message.Builder ()
    .collapseKey ("1")
    .timeToLive (2419200)
    .delayWhileIdle (false)
    .addData ("message", "example message")
    .build ();

result = sender.send (message, reGid, sendCount);
```

Receiving side you have to create a Broadcast Receiver with these actions:

```
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
```

and then when you receive the intent you get the message like this:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType))
{
    //Here you process the intent like you normally would
    //String parameter = intent.getStringExtra("name of parameter");
    //...
    //After that you can create a notification like in the link below.
}
```

**[creating notifications](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html)**

Comment: Aha, i see. I got another activity where I send an friend request to an user. i'm not using GCM but still when I send this friend request it works form device 1 to device 2. tried to do the same on this notification but failed and its only display on device 1.